My Vault policies does not allow me to create/update/delete secrets
I have a problem with Vault from Hashicorp.
I have a server which is set up correctly (I can read from Vault without a problem!) and I connect to it via AppRole.
I have two use-cases which I want to implement.

Create or Update a specific Secret via Code
Delete Metadata of a Secret or Destroy Secret

I have 2 AppRoles. One for the first Use-Case and one for the second one.

CreationAppRole
DeletionAppRole

I have also 2 Policies which I created

CreationPolicy
DeletionPolicy

CreationPolicy:
It should only have the Create and Update Capabilities.
For that my policy looks like this which should allow the creation and updating of secrets to everything that is under: mountpath/data/path/to/secretfolder/. So e.g. the policy should allow me to add a secret under: mountpath/data/path/to/secretfolder/test/test . At least thats how I understand it.
path "mountpath/data/path/to/secretfolder/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}

It is not working and I get an permission denied when I run my code in Java.
DeletionPolicy:
It should only have the delete capability.
For that my policy looks like this which should allow me to delete the metadata of a secret or destroy it completely. The Softdelete is not allowed in my case
path "mountpath/data/path/to/secretfolder/test/*" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list", "delete", "update"]
}

path "mountpath/destroy/path/to/secretfolder/test/*" {
  capabilities = ["delete"]
}

path "mountpath/metadata/path/to/secretfolder/test/*" {
  capabilities = ["delete"]
}

I don't know where my error is. Does anyone have an idea?
What I have done so far:

I checked the link here and check how my policy could be wrong: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2
I checked that my AppRole has the correct policy assigned


Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! When you say I get permission denied when I run my code in Java, does it mean it works on the command line? Try splitting the problem by using the Vault cli. Do a vault login --method approle --role-id CreationAppRole --secret-id .... and try vault kv put ..., then do the same with the delete AppRole. That will ensure you have your policy straight.

I got it. It was an error in my logic.
The Policies that I needed were:
For creation: Use the policy that I mention aboive. It works. I did something wrong in java.
For deletion/Read: You can use the first and the third policy and it works.
There was a problem regarding the rollout of the policies...
I posted it as answer because I don't know how I can close the question otherwise

I got it. It was an error in my logic. The Policies that I needed were: For creation: Use the policy that I mention aboive. It works. I did something wrong in java. For deletion/Read: You can use the first and the third policy and it works. There was a problem regarding the rollout of the policies...
